# Android-Songs List

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and currently working on a project where I list the title of 100 songs. When the user clicks on a song, the window display changes to display the lyrics of the song. I've done a similar project,for 2 buttons, where I used intent to start a new activity(Java class to read text file). Now that I have a 100 text views, is there a way that I can achieve the same result (display content of text files) without creating 100 java classes to read the 100 text files ?

Comment: Creating 100 classes or creating 100 instances of a single class? The first way is bad, the second way is probably ok based on the tiny bit we know about your problem...

Comment: Your question is not clear about what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I'm totally lost as to where you get the idea that you need 100 classes to read 100 text files.  I think it's time for you to post some sample code, because I'm willing to bet that you don't have to do what you think you have to do.

Comment: He is most likely not aware on how to use a ListView for reusing views and displaying the 100 songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a few suggestions:

- Definitely try to go Android Developer [Training Section](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) to get comfortable with use-cases of the most common scenarios in android.
- You are stating that you want to display 100 titles, and so your first thought was to create 100 `TextView` items in your layout. Well, let me tell you that whenever you plan on displaying the same item (by item I mean the same layout) multiple times in one same ContentView, it is a better idea to use a `View` that can handle reuse for you, so your code is simpler to manager. You can either use a `ListView` or a `GridView`.

Basically the `ListView` uses an `Adapter` that will fill as many items as you need it to, using a specified LayoutResource. [Read on how to use the ListView here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

- Once you have created `ListView` on Activity A, set an `OnItemClickListener` to the list, and whenever an Item is clicked, start an `Intent` to launch Activity B; in the `Intent` you can include extras, and therefore you can pass the name of the Song. On Activity B, receive the extra by calling `mIntent.getExtras()`, and then display the lyrics for the supplied song using a `TextView`

I could give you the some sample code, but it seems to me like you are on a very early stage and I don't want to confuse you. Take some time to read through the official docs, they are very helpful! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and tips. I get the Listview done. I'll learn how to set the OnItemClickListener and follow the rest of your suggestions. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please post a sample code of how can you display the .text file for the clicked song?

Comment: Since you have the Lyrics to what I can only imagine are 100 songs, rather than including 100 .text files in the assets folder of your project, create a SQLite Database, it is easier to access, easier to manage, and Android has a fully functional SimpleCursorAdapter to help you display the data.

Comment: The people that I'm developing the app for don't want a database. Your previous suggestions were very helpful. I got the list view working but the problem now when I click on any song, it displays song1.txt, since I have a method that reads InputStream songOne = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.songone);. then it assigns it to string, then gets the textview and finally sets the text. I don't know how to specify which text displays when a song is clicked.

Comment: I filled the elements,songs, of the listview using an array of string.

Comment: Try posting a new question for this and link me to it, this is getting too long for comments.

Comment: I can't ask any more questions. It gives me this warning every time I try Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: The app is done following your tips. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need 100 textview or 100 classes??!!! as far i understand from your question, that you are trying to show the lyrics of a song after clicking on it. If so then you can do this.

in second activity only place 1 textview. when user clicks on a song of first activity then pass a data to second activity to identify the song ( may be song name). Then from the second activity read the lyrics using the song name and show it in textview.

Again why do you need 100 textviews+100 classes. Am I missing something?